# UML Class diagram MVC Pattern for a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, uml

I am working in my very first MVC Project which consist in a online quiz web application. I am currently doing my documentation and I am trying to figure out how my class diagram will look like. There are three types of users Admin, teachers and students.

So far I have reach the conclusion that I need this as a part of my Model:

*UsersDAO
*QuestionsDAO
*Quiz Model
*Quiz Queries

For the controllers I may need a LoginController and QuizController maybe a UserController

I am not sure if I should have a "View" for every "Controller", or if I need a "Controller" for every type of user. The examples that I have found in the internet are very simplistic because they only contain one Action.

Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of UML is to design the system in abstract. Things like controllers and views are implementation details that can vary depending on what system you end up building this in. All you should be modeling is your business objects and the relationships between them, not things like how they will be persisted or how those relationships are managed.

Something like a view or controller is not a universal concept. Not every framework has a concept of those things, and as a result, a model that includes those is by definition *not* "universal". FWIW, I'd also throw shade on modeling things like DAOs, DTOs, View Models, and the like. Those, too, are implementation details, and highly dependent on things like frameworks, data stores, etc.

Comment: Well, I can do both with UML. Though, one should start with the abstract part and refine it later on.

Comment: You can do anything you want, but at a certain point it's not UML you're doing anymore. The moment you cross into implementation details, you're outside of UML.

Comment: That's the whole point of that "universal" bit in the name. What if ultimately one decides to implement this in an MVVM-structured framework. How do you then communicate the idea of a "controller". Since the concept of a controller is not a universal concept, it's not something that should be part of a UML design.

Comment: You can do transformations from abstract to more concrete models (using MDA with CIM, PIM, PSM).

Comment: Thank you Chris I was focusing in reflecting my MVC framework and giving details, that I forgot the basic about UML Diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Your model includes below operations (without login system):

**Teacher** (CRUD), design exam questions, and score answers

**Student** (CRUD), take quiz, and get quiz scores

**Quiz** (CRUD)

So you can implement this model by three `Controller`:

```
TeacherController
StudentController
QuizController
```

For `CRUD` operations you can use a `View` but for other operations you should add new `View`.